# C# Calculate chance of power up

Tags: c#, winforms, 2d-games

I've got some power up in my breakout game. The current way I'm doing it is  generating a random number between 1 & 100 and check that random number: E.g

```
if (powerUpCheck <= 5 && ball.CanCollide && !paddle.IncreaseBatWidth && !explodingBall)
{
    lblPowerUp.Visible = true;
    lblPowerUp.Text = "Power Ball!";
    ball.CanCollide = false;
    enablePowerUp = true;
}

if (powerUpCheck <= 7 && !explodingBall && !paddle.IncreaseBatWidth && ball.CanCollide)
{
    lblPowerUp.Visible = true;
    lblPowerUp.Text = "Exploding Ball!";
    enablePowerUp = true;
    explodingBall = true;
}

if (powerUpCheck <= 20  && !paddle.IncreaseBatWidth && ball.CanCollide && !explodingBall)
{
    lblPowerUp.Visible = true;
    lblPowerUp.Text = "Bigger Bat!";
    enablePowerUp = true;
    paddle.IncreaseBatWidth = true;
}
```

As can tell, the 20% chance one will happen only if it's between 20 and 8 and so on

I thought about doing it like this:

```
if(powerUpCheck >= 20 && powerUpCheck <= 20)
```

But I'm not sure if that is truly 20%...

Comment: If the number is 5 or less, every `if statement will execute - is that what you want?  In your second example, the `if` will only execute if the number is 20, and it'd be simpler to write `if (powerUpCheck == 20)`.

Comment: It will help us all if you ask a direct question...

Comment: `if(powerUpCheck >= 20 && powerUpCheck <= 20)` that would only work when `powerUpCheck == 20`, since it can't be both greater than and less than 20.

Comment: I think you don't understand how that works--unless you have a return statement in your if statements--then if powerUpCheck were 5 or less, then all the code in all three if statements will execute--the "20% chance one will happen only if it's between 20 and 8" statement is not true.

Comment: Sorry for the crappy post, guys. I've been working on the game most of the day and was pretty fatigued when I posted. First of all, what I want is to have x% chance of a power up occurring. Secondly, Ron. It was meant to be `powerUpCheck >= 20 && powerUpCheck <= 40` (typo on my part). And Russ, see my updated code. The previous code was a striped down version, but reading what you said I realised I should've put the rest in.

Answer (score 1):

Code as shown checks for dependent events which may be what you are looking for (get power-up for 20%, and in 25% of that get another, probably improved version).

Usually such events would be independent and you'd just want to check for new `Random` number to fall in particular range:

```
// somewhere in class
static Random powerupRandom = new Random();

var usePowerUp1 = powerupRandom.Next(100) < 5; //(0-4 out of 0-99 - 5%)
var usePowerUp2 = powerupRandom.Next(100) < 7;    
var usePowerUp3 = powerupRandom.Next(100) < 20;
```

Note that if you use `<=` than your percentage would be different: `randomValue <= 5` would have 6% chance - true for 0-5 out of 0-99.

Answer (score 1):

For percentage stuff I prefer using `Random.NextDouble()` which returns a value between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive) `[0,1)`.
Its not a big change, but you can be more precise and you do not have to change the value of your random number all the time (say from 100 to 1000).

```
var powerUpCheck = random.NextDouble();

//5%
if (powerUpCheck < 0.05) 
{
    //Do stuff
}

//7%
if (powerUpCheck < 0.07) 
{
    //Do stuff
}

//20%
if (powerUpCheck < 0.20)
{
    //Do stuff
}

//1 3rd
if (powerUpCheck < 1.0 / 3)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```